# transform multi async call to single

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

i have the code which doing multiply requests

```js
const allCategory = [];
     if (Array.isArray(categoryTreeItems.value)) {
       const categoryFilter = [3338, 4775, 3411, 3995, 3949, 2934, 3071, 3462, 3629, 5239];
       categoryFilter.forEach(async (cate) => {
         const {category: categoryData, search: searchCategoriesData} = useCategory('category-data-search');
         await searchCategoriesData({id: cate});
         if (categoryData.value.image_url.length > 0) {
            allCategory.push(categoryData.value);
         }
       });
     }
```

and i need to send single by 'id:in'
any help?

below is part for which it calls categories

```js
<div class="show-shop-cate" v-show="allCategory.length > 0">
   <div class="position-slide">
      <div class="slide-shop">
         <p class="title-slide font-bold" :style="{color: '#fff'}">{{ "Shop By Category" }}</p>
         <VueSlickCarousel class="custom-slick" v-bind="getSettingSlide()">
            <div v-for="(item, idx) in allCategory" :key="idx" class="custom-item radius-10 cursor-pointer relative">
               <button type="button" @click="pushRouter(item)">
               <img :src="item.image_url" class="radius-10">
               </button>
            </div>
         </VueSlickCarousel>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whatdo you mean by  `by 'id:in'`? Please provide some example.

Comment: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/9cc3a53863922-get-all-categories

there is filter "id: in"
sorry i haven't worked with js couple of months and now getting bunch of errors when trying to change this code

Comment: `forEach` does not support async callback, ie you can define them, but `forEach` won't await them. Use `Promise.all` or a simple `for loop` instead

Comment: @derpirscher 
for some reasons only forEach is working but just calling those 10 categories 1 by 1 takes like 3 more sec to load page

and there is an option to call all with 'id:in' instead but cannot figure how
trying all the ways and nothing works

Answer (score 1):

You can use Promise.all() and a map() instead of a forEach.

```js
    const allCategory = [];
    if (Array.isArray(categoryTreeItems.value)) {
      const categoryFilter = [3338, 4775, 3411, 3995, 3949, 2934, 3071, 3462, 3629, 5239];
      await Promise.all(categoryFilter.map(async (cate) => {
        const {category: categoryData, search: searchCategoriesData} = useCategory('category-data-search');
        await searchCategoriesData({id: cate});
        if (categoryData.value.image_url.length > 0) {
          allCategory.push(categoryData.value);
        }
      }));
    }
```

Comment: 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.ts(1308)

Comment: @karenjan This code belongs to async function then

Answer (score 0):

Reading how an id:'in' works,it seems to me you have to collect the ids in an array & join them with ','.The following should do the trick.

```
const promises = [];
let ids =[]; // id's to be collected 
let result // result 
if (Array.isArray(categoryTreeItems.value)) {
       const categoryFilter = [3338, 4775, 3411, 3995, 3949, 2934, 3071, 3462, 3629, 5239];
       categoryFilter.forEach((cate) => {
         const {category: categoryData, search: searchCategoriesData} = useCategory('category-data-search');
          ids.push(cate)
         
         if (categoryData.value.image_url.length > 0) {
            allCategory.push(categoryData.value);
         }
       });
      results = await searchCategoriesData({id: `in=${ids.join(',')}`})
     }
```

Comment: this code send call for each category
i need to send 1 call for all categories with id's array and where "id: cate" replace "id" by 'id:in'

Comment: @karenjan You need to be more explicit in your question. We don't know the rest of your code and the context. If you need something more than a Promise.all() please add details to your question.

Comment: @anuragb26
that's the code which calls categories for category slider at homepage (headless vue)
and way which i've added above takes a lot of time to get categories + send bunch of calls

i`m adding part of code for which it calls categories

Comment: @karenjan,I have updated the answer with id=in from what i could understand using this link https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D51B00004P5aglSAB/api-given-a-list-of-product-ids-how-can-we-get-the-product-list-with-one-call?language=en_US

Comment: @anuragb26
[Vue warn]: Property or method "allCategory" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')